# Type inference not working while using generic extends?

Tags: typescript

So I have this following code:

```
type Settings = Record<string, "required" | "optional">
type Item<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>

function create<S extends Settings>(settings: S, items: Item<S> | Item<S>[]) {}

const s: Settings = {
    email: "required"
}

create(s, {
    // no type inferencce on email
})
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=3#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDzrAkqoA0UARCRAI4CuirZTUAPsyJgkRZAEMANkwB8AWABQoSFACSwCAFsKAFRnYoABXEkkUivmLkKAawggiAMyg7G45CBnyFixx2QEoshQBKziGhQwUBAAHhrIZJhwCHToMgAU6PBIaOgAXLCMiBqa+WolkfqC6lqVANoAugCUUADeAL6KisTI1FBlyTkYBq2KUOPRmuKIkgUs7Fw8TIqdPgqhEOEQmYyjChNQAPSHUMhEUMrQKI4QrAEE0GKT05IrTUA)

[image]

How do I make typescript inference work on second parameter of `create()` function? Could it be because of `S extends Settings`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the type of `Settings` generic based on the keys in the settings object, which will propagate the "email" property in your settings object to the "Settings" type.

```
type Settings<Keys extends keyof Record<string, string>> = {
    [key in Keys]: string
};

// type will be inferred :)
const s = {
    email: "required",
    password: "required",
}

type Item<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, any>>

function create<Keys extends string, S extends Settings<Keys>>(
    settings: S,
    items: Item<S> | Item<S>[]
) {}

create(s, {
    email: "",
    // password: "",
})
```

Verify that IntelliSense works in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDKtzgJYDsDmBnAPANKyQ7ywAe4sGAJqQNbED2AZvAEqwDGTATjXhzhemLABp4QkdgB8M+AF54Ab1Dx18ANqNI8TPCIkAugC5Jw0aAC+AblCgeGIZMUq1G2AFsAhmgA2ZgBEvLAAjgCuaCE0gWLu6tDeODgA7nw0QSERUbAxcSBW9iBQcPAAklSeeAAq8koACt686N5+eJw8-Hg6rPDVEt4YkHJFLOEYXOhMGPBcId5UhMSkFFS0pFKiEohklNR0SCjo2PiGOHIAFPGSR6I4Zoj5GnqV9+WVeIjyAD7vXp8yTRGUAAShUhTAIDmsAWsAuOAkqhAzy8vgC8ECsWuAHpsfBEsk0vwgliCiCgA)

Comment: I want type inference on `const s` as well. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to the updated question

Basically it is the same issue as in the original question (see below).

The differences are:

- now we must also use `as const` for the `settings` variable so that typescript will not widen the `"required"` type to string
- and change the `Item` type to allow `"required" | "optional"`

```js
type Settings = Record<string, "required" | "optional">
type Item<T> = Partial<Record<keyof T, "required" | "optional">>

function create<S extends Settings>(
    settings: S,
    items: Item<S> | Item<S>[]
) {}


const settings = {
    email: "required"
} as const;

create(settings, {
    email: "optional"
})

create({
    value: "optional"
}, [{
    value: "required"
}])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDzrAkqoA0UARCRAI4CuirZTUAPsyJgkRZAEMANkwB8AWABQoSFACSwCAFsKAFRnYoABXEkkUivmLkKAawggiAMyg7GLdlx59BTYaInSMvIKio4cyAT%20UASs4hoUMFAQAB4ayGSYcAh06DIAFIpQRVDo8Eho6ABcsPSFxYgamlVqjQn6gupabQDaALqKAJRQAN4AvooTCsTI1CVlOQbDdUVa4oiS1e6c3BC8iqNQ4pjT1ADckzEQcRB5pdkVjEsKxUmaaxtCIohiUkz7AxdYho8k8XgA3KQcCCbPzfAJ-BSjRjdUHFCGSKGbVjbLz7XoDIA)

## Answer to original question

### The issue

is that you tell type-script that `s` is a record of string:

```js
const s: Settings = {
    email: "required"
}
```

so the compiler cannot assume that `s.email` exists.

e.g. you can do this:

```js
delete s.email
s.email.toLocaleLowerCase() // Runtime Error!
```

### Solution

So the simplest way to get type-checking is to remove the type (`Settings`) form your `s` variable.

```js
const settings = {
    email: "required"
}

delete settings.email // compile error
```

[Playground](http://%20https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDzrAkqoA0U1taAfALABQokUAksAgBbCgBVW2KAAUAhiSQyANhXzFyFANYQQRAGZRRjGchCsOnLroCuyAkiLIoBEhBmCKMKBAAeg5GUw4BDp0VgAKLigopngkNHQALlh6SOjEQSFE-gyPCQAfbOFcgG0AXS4ASigAbwBfLgbOYmRqJklq1KjhGURFJIAiFwBHK0QXMn6ueosmlzcIMPRGDs5oqAB6dahkIigeaBRdCBdbaAALY4gpiqA)

Now you can see that typescript knows that `s` has for sure an email-property
[image]

Compare this to your example (note the `abc` icon in the completion dialog - [VS Code ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions)):
[image]

With this change type-completion will work: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhzAJYDsDmBnKBeKAlCAxgPYBOAJgDzrAkqoA0U1taAfALABQokUAksAgBbCgBVW2KAAUAhiSQyANmI6cuAMwCuyAkiLIoBEhBmCKMKBAAeg5GUxwEddKwAUXKJ6bwkadAC5Yeg8vREEhAP5w8wkAHyjhGIBtAF0uAEooAG8AXy58zmJkam8nP0kskM9hGURFQIAiYwBHTURjMgauHIBuLgB6fqgyCEV4aHQfZwA6GrqCoxNBV0myjEZKzi9LIVr6qAauzhz0heNTCFdN7YA3JU0IRrvFI5zGJOuvZ4fGgEYAJgAzK8UukgA)

Note: Maybe you also want to change the item type to:

```js
type Item<T> = Partial<T>
```

so that the `items` parameter properties must also be strings

Comment: But there will be no type inference(`type Settings = Record<string, "required" | "optional">`) on settings.

Comment: Well, that's a different question then - I'll update the answer